# What's the math behind Vector multiplication?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

Can someone explain to me why a cylinder with this node tree becomes a double-sided cone?

I have tried to check it and to calculate it by hand using a vector $(3,0,0)$ but can't figure it out. The green dotted line is supposed to represent the side of the cylinder befor the math operation. Somehow the vector $(3,0,0)$ must become the vector $(0,0,0)$.

In the node tree, the separate xyz node takes the $z$ value and makes it the $x$ and $y$ value of the new vector, while $z$ is defined as $1$.

Then the vectors are multiplied with each other. I am not a mathematician but according to chatGPT the cross product can be used to calculate this. obviously $(-3,-3,3)$ is the result. But it must be $(0,0,0)$.

[image: SCreenshot]

Comment: That position node is a field node, and will not reference the object location, but instead the position of each point as it is processed through the tree.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your test case

Comment: Cross product is different, vector multiply is multiplication straight across, so the result here is 0,0,0

Comment: You're multiplying the position vectors of all your points by 1 on the Z, so their height does not change. But you're multiplying their horizontal placement (X and Y values) by their heights. The ones on the upper part just get bigger since they're being multiplied by a positive number, but the ones on the lower part "flip" (all the while getting bigger) since they're being multiplied by a negative number (their Z is below 0). Since the bottom "flips" but the top stays fixed, it twists, creating this cone shape.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of what's happening: https://i.imgur.com/Ewp7DX6.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - I would strongly recommend against using ChatGPT as a general knowledge engine. It has frequently been shown to provide confident, totally incorrect answers. For instance, the cross product of $(3,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ is $(0,-3,0)$, not $(-3,-3,3)$

Second, you're using element-wise multiplication: for vertices on the center circle of your cylinder $(z=0)$ and your current node setup, you're performing

$(x,y,z) * (z, z, 1) = (xz, yz, z) = (0, 0, 0)$

Change your vector math node to "Cross Product" and you should be in business.

Comment: @quellenform Careful, ChatGPT will come for you one day :)

Comment: @Neil Seriously, I prefer to learn and know things myself rather than depend on an AI. Therefore: Rather no, because the day will come when real knowledge counts, completely independent of an assisting mechanism ;-)

Comment: @quellenform I agree with you, we definitely need to avoid reliance on AI, but I'm certain it's going to be a valuable tool for us in many ways.